# delete all rows after 100 in a table in mysql (without auto_increment)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to delete all rows after 100th row in a table in mysql. For some reason this table does not have any coloumn with Auto_increment or primary key. How can I delete all rows after 100th row? what can be the query for this?

**as I think** that I have to add another column in my table with auto_increment and then delete after 100th row and then remove this column? or any better suggestion?

The actual problem aroused when I was copying all rows from 1 table to another and mistakenly duplicated all rows in the same table through a sql dump file. So, now I want to delete all rows after 100th row.

Comment: Do you have a field that indicates in what order they were entered?  A datetime field perchance?

Comment: How are you determining the 100th row? Do you have a specific order? Have you tried a `LIMIT` clause?

Comment: Why not just delete all the duplicates? In addition when you say after the 100st row, how is the table sorted? Or do you have an id field?

Comment: There is no such thing as the "*100th row*" in relational database.

Comment: I can get 100 rows with query _select * from abc limit 100_ but how can I delete after 100th row

Comment: Make a count to that table, and when you have 100 records, make a function to delete.

Comment: If you're using a language it would be a little easier.  You could SELECT field FROM tbl LIMIT 100, 50

This will grab 50 rows starting from the 100th.  Then in a loop you could get each row's unique field and delete that row

Answer (score 1):

This deletes every SECOND row starting with the first (ex: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 => 2,4,6)

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE rand() < 0.5
```

---

This deletes all rows after your set id

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id > row_number
```

---

I hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use swap temp table.
Say you table name is mytable;

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mytable_temp LIKE mytable;
INSERT INTO mytable_temp SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 100;
DELETE FROM mytable;
INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM mytable_temp;
DROP TABLE mytable_temp;
```

**Note:** In general case when the duplicate rows are unordered or you don't know where the original rows end you can set unique index on (all) swap table columns and use REPLACE instead of INSERT. Then there is no need for using LIMIT.

Comment: don't you think my suggestion is better to add another column in table with auto_increment and then delete after 100th row and then remove this column?

Comment: Here you don't have to have ALTER privilege. Also in general case you can get rid of duplicates even if the data is unordered (see edit).